# CORS Issue on iframe to current Laravel route

Tags: laravel, iframe, cors

I am pulling in an Iframe that has javascript included in it. I have installed the fruitcake cors package and set the config file to be wide open. I also added the "Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header to the xmlhttp request just in case because I am confused on who is actually denying the request. Here is the error I am getting -

```
Access to XMLHttpRequest at "https://site-that-i-am-posting-to" from origin "https://where-the-iframe-is-sourced-from" has been blocked by CORS policy: Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present of the requested resource.
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [XMLHttpRequest cannot load XXX No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35553500/xmlhttprequest-cannot-load-xxx-no-access-control-allow-origin-header)

Comment: *I also added the "Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header to the xmlhttp request* — That can only make things worse.

Comment: @Quentin ya, its lengthy but kinda makes sense. I am just confused on which site needs to add the headers. The one the iframe is on or the Laravel site?

Comment: `https://site-that-i-am-posting-to` is who is denying the request (more accurately the browser is denying the request because `https://site-that-i-am-posting-to` is not sending back the correct CORS headers)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Figured it out. I needed to add the correct request headers to the xmlhttprequest like this -

```
xhrapi.setRequestHeader('Origin', 'https://site-posting-from.com');
xhrapi.setRequestHeader('Access-Control-Request-Method', 'POST');
```

And then it worked. Thanks to anyone that tried to help!